# broken headers causes too many x-spam points

Tags: php, spamassassin

I use my hosting provider's mail server and email formed by my php scripts gets to many x-spam points. Mostly because of broken_headers. How can i fix the headers so my email wouldn't be considered as spam ?

```
header('Location: thanks/thanks.html');

header('X-mailer:PHP');
```

that's my php code regarding headers

Comment: That's... not how you create email headers. I'd suggest you look at the [mail documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) to find out how to create them properly.

Comment: oops, that's wrong line; 
--
$headers = "from: maproject.ml<project25018@maproject.ml>\r\nContent-type : text/html;charset=UTF-8\r\n";
--
here it is

Comment: Other than the space between Content-Type and the colon, it looks mostly correct. If you can, take a look at the headers on the received email and see if there's anything there that might help.